# How to add var in get value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add var in get value in JavaScript ?

I have 2 var

```
var page = $('#demoajax').val();

var name = $("#users").val();
```

This is mym old code

```
data:"server=Windows&actionfunction=showData&page="+page,
```

I want to add `var name` and value `now=date` to this line how can I do that ?

First I try this

```
data:"username="+name+"&server=Windows&actionfunction=showData&page="+page+"&now=date",
```

But not work.

Comment: name.toString() and date.toString()

Comment: If this is part of an Ajax request, make your life simpler and pass an object to `data` instead. What does "not work" mean here?

Comment: Use the console.log() function to see what you have in variables. Maybe are empty...

Comment: very ambiguous queestion.. do you have special characters or foreign letters?  will cause an encoding issue with GET causing you not to be able to pass parameters

Comment: What is the result and what is the error? Should the static string "now=date" appear in the query? "But not work" is a very bad description of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have inserted your changes in the middle of the query string. Try this instead.

```
data:"server=Windows&username="+name+"&actionfunction=showData&page="+page+"&now=date",
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `data:"username="+name+"&server=Windows&actionfunction=showData&page="+page+"&date=now",`
  switch date and now

Also lose the comma at end if not needed

Comment: Somehow what you posted is different than the code in the question.

Comment: I just copied it from his .. no idea how it got different.. never mind.. I changed it..  thanks for pointing it out ! :)